The condition of Drawing two tangent lines to an convex function through a point
When doing Math exercises,I have the following question about tangent lines to a curve.

For an explicit, second order differentiable function, we assume that f ''(x)>0 (x belongs to [a,b]), i.e. f(x) is a convex function, without loss of generality. What's the sufficient and necessary condition that we can draw 2 tangent lines to the curve from a point on the plain?   Intuitively, the condition is that the point is in the closed region formed by the curve itself and the 2 tangent lines at the begining and the end of the closed interval.But how to prove this mathematically?
My attempt is to write the tangent line's function of any 2 points on the curve and solve for the intersection P. I can show that the point is above both the tangent lines, but how can I show it is a sufficient condition?

You can define the grey region to be the one below $f$ and above both tangents. This avoids speaking of the intersection of the two tangents.

Consider the two rays of a tangent line emitting from the point of tangency separately. Because $f'' > 0, f'$ is increasing, so the right-pointing tangent ray at $a$ has the lowest slope and starts farthest left. Use this to show that the other right-pointing tangent rays lie above the tangent ray of $a$. And similarly show that the left-pointing tangent rays lie above the left-pointing ray at $b$. Any point on two tangents will be on a left-pointing tangent ray and a right-pointing tangent ray, and so must lie above both end rays.
